# How to find questions on some topics?

Tags: support, questions

If suppose i want to list out all questions of C language group then how can i list out all questions to give answers or to refer.

Comment: Use tags ("A tag is a keyword or label that categorizes your question with other, similar questions"). For example, for questions tagged under "C" use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can used the advanced search options.

> [image: tips]

Thus, you can see, to search for all questions tagged with C, you search for `[c]`

Comment: where is this option ?

Comment: @Vikrant These are all available from [the search bar](http://prntscr.com/15wuxa).